# Get different values from 1 table to different values of other table

Tags: php, sql

I have 2 tables

1.empmaster

```
empcode      | empname

1            | shahrukh khan
2            | salman khan
```

2.taskdetails

```
taskregecode | taskacecode

1            | 2
```

I Need to print it as follows in PHP:

```
taskregecode = 1    =>    shahrukh khan   &   taskregecode = 2    =>    salman khan
```

In taskdetails, I have only one record which uses 2 **empnames** from 'empmaster'.

How do I do it?

Comment: `SELECT empcode, empname
FROM empmaster e INNER JOIN taskdetails t
ON e.empcode = taskregecode
OR e.empcode = taskacecode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to join empmaster twice with taskdetails to get corresponding name for taskregecode and taskacecode

```
select td.taskregecode,
       e1.empname as taskregename,
       td.taskacecode,
       e2.empname as taskacename
from  taskdetails td
join empmaster e1 on e1.empcode = td.taskregecode 
join empmaster e2 on e2.empcode = td.taskacecode
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b75ff9/1)